# upgrade mongodb

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I'm looking for the easiest and the most recommended way to upgrade mongodb version (standalone server and mongodb shell).

Are there any terminal (for mac) commands that i can follow in order to upgrade?

I tried to stop the server by 
$ mongo

> use admin
>   db.shutdownServer()
>   i get : 
>   Sat Mar 17 20:38:15 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
>   Sat Mar 17 20:38:15 query failed : admin.$cmd { shutdown: 1.0 } to: 127.0.0.1:27017
>   server should be down...
>   Sat Mar 17 20:38:15 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
>   Sat Mar 17 20:38:15 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017

I understand that after stopping the server i need to change the bin folder of mongodb. (which i'm failing to do because mongo is in use)

If someone knows an easier way to only upgrade the mongodb version i would really thank him/her!
thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

shutdown mongodb with:

```
/usr/bin/mongodb --config $PATH-TO-CONFIG --shutdown
```

(replace /usr/bin with the right directory)
copy new mongodb and restart mongodb afterwards.

Answer (score 49):

To **Upgrade MongoDB** on **Ubuntu**

First, **Backup your data** using [Mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)

e.g:

```
mongoexport --db sales --collection contacts --out contacts.json --journal
```

Then check which version of MongoDB you are running by issuing the command:

> $ mongod --version
>
> db version **v1.8.2**, pdfile version 4.5 - 
>   Wed Oct 24 15:43:13 git version: nogitversion

*Confirm* if mongo is currently running:

> $ ps -deaf | grep **mongod**
>
> **mongodb  15408**     1  0 Jun06 ?  13:50:00 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf

To [Shutdown MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo)

> $ ./mongo
>
> > use admin
>
> > db.shutdownServer()
>
> server should be down...

Then upgraded following these instructions: [How to Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Add the 10 Gen (creators of MongoDB) public key to apt-get so you trust their package:

> $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
>
> $ echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list

Update your packages:

> $ sudo apt-get update

install 10gen's MongoDB Debian/Ubuntu package:

> $ sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
>
> The following packages will be **REMOVED**:
>     **mongodb**
>
> The following **NEW** packages will be installed:
>     **mongodb-10gen**

*If you get an error*, try:

> $ apt-get autoremove

Confirm that the **mongodb** user/group has permission to write to the data directory:

> $ sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/.

Start up MongoDB *as a Daemon* (background process) using the following command:

> $ mongod --fork --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --smallfiles --logpath
>   /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend

To [Shut Down MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo) enter the Mongo CLI, access the admin and issue the shutdown command:

> $ ./mongo
>
> > use admin
>
> > db.shutdownServer()

Comment: Perfect instructions! Thank you. The only problem I had was starting the daemon... I had to use `sudo` otherwise it complained about not being able to write to the log path.

Comment: Really useful!  I had to do a couple of extra things, though:

I got `bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list: Permission denied` when running `echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list`.  I tried various things, but in the end just echoed to terminal and copied-and-pasted into the file.

Also, the install failed for me and said `trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongo', which is also in package mongodb-clients 1:2.0.4-1ubuntu2.1`, so I had to `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-clients` first.

Comment: It's better to use "|" in the echo instead of the ">>", i.e.: echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list

Comment: **** You should say to backup your data all my data was lost****

Comment: @liadlivnat I've added the Mongoexport link. and CLI line. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the version upgrade, but usually if it's a major upgrade (example from 1.8.xx to 2.0.XX) you should do at least the following steps:

- backup your data (mongoexport or check this [MongoDB backup documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Backups))
- stop the server (use admin db.shutdownServer() )
- copy or symbolic link the new mongodb binaries
- run mongod with the --upgrade flag (mongod - f  --upgrade)
- when upgrade done, restart the mongod server

After that make sure that everything is working properly. If not switch back to the old version, import the data from the backup and check [mongoDB jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) :)

Answer (score 3):

**1.Import the public key used by the package management system**

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927

**2.    Create a list file for MongoDB.**

echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list

**3. Reload local package database.**
sudo apt-get update

**4. stop the existing service**
sudo service mongodb stop

**5. first migrate to 2.4 to 2.6**
**Install a specific release of MongoDB**

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=2.6.12 mongodb-org-server=2.6.12 mongodb-org-shell=2.6.12 mongodb-org-mongos=2.6.12 mongodb-org-tools=2.6.12

**6.unlink the temp links**
remove the lock file.
rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

**7.restart mongo service**
sudo service mongodb restart

**8. Now finally migrate from 2.6 to 3.0**
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.0.12 mongodb-org-server=3.0.12 mongodb-org-shell=3.0.12 mongodb-org-mongos=3.0.12 mongodb-org-tools=3.0.12

restart again and voila !!!!

For more details follow the official documentation:
[mongo doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 2):

### To upgrade from version 2 to version 3

I was unsuccessful using the methods in the other answers here, and was finally successful when following the [offical document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/)'s "**Upgrade Binaries**" approach, like so:

1. **Stop mongo from running** :

   `$ sudo service mongod stop`
2. **Download the correct binaries**

   > (from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#previous), and for help getting the correct version see [this
   >   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41625556/1290746))
3. **Copy the downloaded binaries over** :

   `$ sudo cp downloaded_binaries/bin/* /usr/bin`
4. **Restart mongo** :

   `$ sudo service mongod start`