# when i upgrade mongo it still says version 2.x.x , how can i go to a higher version?

Tags: mongodb

### How do I upgrade from mongo version 2 to version 3 ?

I am trying to upgrade from mongo 2.x.x to the latest version (which at the time is 3.2.x).

The [official (3.2 upgrade) instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-upgrade/) say I need to go to version 3.0.x first and so that is all i'm trying to achieve right now - to get from version 2 to version 3.

#### First try : `apt-get`

I first tried using `apt-get`, following these [instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/?_ga=1.214251735.1796139716.1477605721) (linked to from [this page](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community), which was linked to from [these official (3.0 upgrade) instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/)).
That all appeared to work alright, however my version (`$ mongo --version`) number didn't change, so no upgrade actually happened at all.

#### Second try : mongod-10gen

I then found [these instructions](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) and followed them.
This time, again, every step was successful but the end result was that my version has now gone *down*! (from 2.6.1 to 2.4.14)

I've also tried following the instructions in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13078276/1290746), which are essentially the same as the other instructions - and gave the same result - success on every step, but the final result is still a v2 mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Third try : copy the binaries

[The official (3.0 upgrade) instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/) actually first suggest downloading and copying over the binaries (but I tried the auto install instructions first because that seemed easier).

My binaries are all actually directly in `/usr/bin/`.

1. **Get the url for the binaries for your system** (for the curl command below) **from the [download binaries page](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#previous)**.
   (For me it was for Ubuntu 14, for previous release, v3.0.14)

[image]

2. Then download the binaries, and copy them directly into `/usr/bin/`.

Like so:

```
$ curl https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1404-3.0.14.tgz -o mongo_3.0.14.tgz
$ tar -xvf mongo_3.0.14.tgz
$ sudo service mongod stop # stop DB
$ sudo cp mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1404-3.0.14/bin/* /usr/bin
$ sudo service mongod start # and restart
$ mongo --version
```

> MongoDB shell version: 3.0.14

### Success!!

*So, the correct approach was to follow the initial instructions - however it was not obvious to me what "copy the binaries" meant at first, and the alternative auto install with `apt-get` I really thought would be the simple and right way to go (why doesn't that work??) - I suspect others will come across this problem so I will put this third try as an answer and still post the question*